# Ajax posting from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

newbie to ajax here. I am trying to post some data to a php file on my server, however, the data is not passing thru. I have a dynamically created table from the results of a query. I am trying to use document.getElementById but that does not grab my data (and it makes sence that it doesn't since each dynamically created row will have the same id I guess) I have also tried passing the the variables in a function like so:

```
print("<tr onclick='ajax_post({$result["date"]}, {$result["work"]});'>");
```

and on the js function grabbing the variables like so:

```
ajax_post(a, b){
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create variables to send to our PHP file
var url = "ajaxform.php";
var dt = a;
var wk = b;
var vars = "date="+dt+"&workout="+wk;
}
```

but this doesn't work here. Here is my code:

```
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
 var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create variables to send to our PHP file
var url = "ajaxform.php";
var dt = document.getElementById("date").value;
var wk = document.getElementById("work").value;
var vars = "date="+dt+"&workout="+wk;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables       in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status     div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>

<p id="status"></p>

<div>
  <table class="table table-striped">  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="bold">Date</th>
        <th class="bold">Work</th>
        <th class="bold">Mood</th>              
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>      
<?php       

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {   
            print("<tr onclick='ajax_post();'>");

                print("<td class='date' id='date' name='date'  value='{$result["date"]}'>{$result["date"]}</td>");
                print("<td id='workout' name='workout' value='{$result["work"]}'>{$result["work"]}</td>");
                print("<td>{$result["mood"]}</td>");        

            print("</tr>");                

        }                     

  ?>        

  </tbody>   
 </table>    

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im open to a jquery solution if it is not feasable to do this with plain js.

Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `$.ajax()` to simplify things a bit. But besides that, you should use `classes` not `ids` to target your elements because `ids` should always be unique (only one element should have that id) while any number of elements can have the same `class`.

When a user clicks a row, find the elements you need in that row and get their values, then send them in the ajax call.

Here's an example:

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/s9Ugr/447/)

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var url = "ajaxform.php";
  var dt = row.find(".date").text();
  var wk = row.find(".work").text();
  var vars = "date=" + dt + "&workout=" + wk;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: vars,
    success: function(response) {
      // handel successs
    },
    error: function(response) {
      // handel error
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="date">1/2/2015</td>
        <td class="work">legs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date">1/3/2015</td>
        <td class="work">arms</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date">1/4/2015</td>
        <td class="work">lats</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date">1/5/2015</td>
        <td class="work">calves</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date">1/6/2015</td>
        <td class="work">quads</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was unsure about using classes and how to access only the calling element and all the elements of that class like so var row = $(this); thanks!!!!