# Save data from dynamically created rows to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter. I have created a table that contains different columns. I wanted to create rows dynamically when clicking on the '+' button. Now i am able to create rows using jquery. I want to save the data to database. how can i save the values of each rows to database when i click on the '+' button?

Comment: Provide more details, with some code which you have have tried. Also read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow

Comment: similar question [solved here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32292891/456135)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax request on this.

First when you click `+` button, instead of just text in each column, you can put input fields.

```
<tr>
 <td><input id="field1" type="text" /></td>
 <td><input id="field2" type="text" /></td>
 <td><input id="field3" type="text" /></td>
 <td><button id="save"></button></td>
<tr>
```

After that, you can assign an event to the `button#save`. When it is click, it will get all the inputs from the fields then store in variable and call an ajax request. You should prepare a php code to handle this request.

```
$('#save').on('click', function() {
   var data = { 
       field1: $('input#field1').val(), 
       field2: $('input#field2').val(), 
       field3: $('input#field3').val()
   };

   // call ajax request
   $.post(url + '/controller/save', data, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }); 
}
```

In your `controller` you should have that `save` method that handle the request.

```
public function save() {
    if($_POST) {
      // get input
      // call model to save data to db
    }
}
```

#### Updated Here

You can have a button save to save all the data.

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    var data = $('input').serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

Then just use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see the posted values in your method in controller.

Comment: y=1; $("#table1").on("click",".plus", function(){
    y++;
$("#table1").append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="qual_'+ y +'" name="qual[]"/></td><td><input type="text" id="inst_' + y +'" name="inst[]"/></td><td><input type="text" id="year_'+ y +'" name="year[]"/></td><td><input type="text" id="mark'+ y + '" name="mark[]"/></td><td><a href="" class="cancel">Remove</a></td></tr>');}
                        This is my code to append rows, and the rows should be created dynamically when clicking on the button. It is working and now i want to save the values in each rows to database.

Comment: Just don't bother with the `ids` just retain your `name` and use `$('input').serialize()`